# R xts lag() function only lags 1 position

Tags: r, xts

I have some confusion about the xts lag() function.  No matter what value I assign for k, I get the identical 1 position lag.

Using the examples from https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xts/versions/0.12-0/topics/diff.xts:

```
(x <- xts(1:10, Sys.Date()+1:10))
(x1 = lag(x))
(x2 = lag(x, k=2))
(lag(x, k=-1, na.pad=FALSE))

           [,1]
2020-04-20    1
2020-04-21    2
2020-04-22    3
2020-04-23    4
2020-04-24    5
2020-04-25    6
2020-04-26    7
2020-04-27    8
2020-04-28    9
2020-04-29   10
           [,1]
2020-04-20   NA
2020-04-21    1
2020-04-22    2
2020-04-23    3
2020-04-24    4
2020-04-25    5
2020-04-26    6
2020-04-27    7
2020-04-28    8
2020-04-29    9
           [,1]
2020-04-20   NA
2020-04-21    1
2020-04-22    2
2020-04-23    3
2020-04-24    4
2020-04-25    5
2020-04-26    6
2020-04-27    7
2020-04-28    8
2020-04-29    9
           [,1]
2020-04-20   NA
2020-04-21    1
2020-04-22    2
2020-04-23    3
2020-04-24    4
2020-04-25    5
2020-04-26    6
2020-04-27    7
2020-04-28    8
2020-04-29    9
```

What might I be failing to understand here?

Comment: Check again. When I run the code, x2 has a shift of 2. The -1 is a special case, check documentation with `?lag.xts`

Comment: Hmmm...  ?lag.xts gives the expected result, but ?lag gives something totally different headed shift {data.table}.  Changing the function calls to lag.xts(...) makes them work as expected.  So, I assume that the xts lag function is getting overlaid with something else.  How can I find out from which package, seeing as xps::lag(...), which I thought was the correct syntax for calling a function within a package, was rejected with no package named xps?

Comment: Please read my answer below. You might have found the solution yourself if you had really made your question reproducible, i.e. included all `library` calls ;)

Comment: @jay.sf Indeed, but I blamed my lack of fundamental knowledge rather than R allowing objects to be silently overlaid.  Thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 4):

It's highly likely `dplyr` that's causing the mess.

```
library(dplyr)   
# Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
# 
# The following objects are masked from ‘package:xts’:
#   
#   first, last
# 
# The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
#   
#   filter, lag  <-------------------------------------------   !!!
# 
# The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
#   
#   intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```

You may carefully read those starting messages and add `stats::` before the function in this case (look up `?lag` and you'll see a list of alterntives).

*Comparison:*

```
cbind(stats::lag(x), stats::lag(x, k=2), stats::lag(x, k=-1, na.pad=F))
#            stats..lag.x. stats..lag.x..k...2. stats..lag.x..k....1..na.pad...F.
# 2020-04-21            NA                   NA                                 2
# 2020-04-22             1                   NA                                 3
# 2020-04-23             2                    1                                 4
# 2020-04-24             3                    2                                 5
# 2020-04-25             4                    3                                 6
# 2020-04-26             5                    4                                 7
# 2020-04-27             6                    5                                 8
# 2020-04-28             7                    6                                 9
# 2020-04-29             8                    7                                10
# 2020-04-30             9                    8                                NA

cbind(dplyr::lag(x), dplyr::lag(x, k=2), dplyr::lag(x, k=-1, na.pad=F))
#            dplyr..lag.x. dplyr..lag.x..k...2. dplyr..lag.x..k....1..na.pad...F.
# 2020-04-21            NA                   NA                                NA
# 2020-04-22             1                    1                                 1
# 2020-04-23             2                    2                                 2
# 2020-04-24             3                    3                                 3
# 2020-04-25             4                    4                                 4
# 2020-04-26             5                    5                                 5
# 2020-04-27             6                    6                                 6
# 2020-04-28             7                    7                                 7
# 2020-04-29             8                    8                                 8
# 2020-04-30             9                    9                                 9
```

`xts::lag.xts` is actually a method of the `xts` package that tells `stats::lag` how to deal with time series. However you may use it directly as you already discovered. Both results are identical.

```
cbind(lag.xts(x), lag.xts(x, k=2), lag.xts(x, k=-1, na.pad=F))
#            lag.xts.x. lag.xts.x..k...2. lag.xts.x..k....1..na.pad...F.
# 2020-04-21         NA                NA                              2
# 2020-04-22          1                NA                              3
# 2020-04-23          2                 1                              4
# 2020-04-24          3                 2                              5
# 2020-04-25          4                 3                              6
# 2020-04-26          5                 4                              7
# 2020-04-27          6                 5                              8
# 2020-04-28          7                 6                              9
# 2020-04-29          8                 7                             10
# 2020-04-30          9                 8                             NA
```

**Note:** Maybe you load some packages automatically with a manipulated `.rprofile` file. I'd recommend not to do such things and delete `library/require` calls there. Another possibility is that you load another package that uses `dplyr` as dependency (e.g. `tidyverse'). Anyway, in all cases the solution above works (but it is tedious to find out every time which base R function has been overwritten again by some sloppy package!).

Comment: Packages imports should really have local (file) not global scope! A really bad design decision in my opinion.

Comment: @DavidWaterworth: My explorations in R at an early stage, but it is alarming to trip over such a fundamental management issue quite so early on.

Comment: The dplyr team is aware of this. [At first](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/277), Hadley was sympathetic. [Then](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/commit/f8a46e030b7b899900f2091f41071619d0a46288) he clobbered `stats::lag` again. He [gave a silly/misleading reason](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1586) later (it has nothing to do with "lots of R pkgs"). This is fixable, but [they don't seem willing](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2195#issuecomment-395750607) to be less anti-social. E.g. `dplyr::lag(ts(1:9))` errors instead of calling `stats::lag`.